# Get full article in Google Sheet using Openai

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch, openai-api

I'm trying to get full article in Google Sheet using Openai API. In column A I just mention the topic and want to get full article in column B.

Here is what I'm trying

```
    /**
 * Use GPT-3 to generate an article
 * 
 * @param {string} topic - the topic for the article
 * @return {string} the generated article
 * @customfunction
 */
function getArticle(topic) {
  // specify the API endpoint and API key
  const api_endpoint = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions';
  const api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

  // specify the API parameters
  const api_params = {
    prompt: topic,
    max_tokens: 1024,
    temperature: 0.7,
    model: 'text-davinci-003',
  };

  // make the API request using UrlFetchApp
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api_endpoint, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + api_key,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(api_params),
  });

  // retrieve the article from the API response
  const json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  if (json.data && json.data.length > 0) {
    const article = json.data[0].text;
    return article;
  } else {
    return 'No article found for the given topic.';
  }
}
```

How can I get the article?

Comment: Print your `json` content.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a modification point. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw the official document of OpenAI API, in your endpoint of `https://api.openai.com/v1/completions`, it seems that the following value is returned. [Ref](https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions)

  ```
    {
      "id": "cmpl-uqkvlQyYK7bGYrRHQ0eXlWi7",
      "object": "text_completion",
      "created": 1589478378,
      "model": "text-davinci-003",
      "choices": [
        {
          "text": "\n\nThis is indeed a test",
          "index": 0,
          "logprobs": null,
          "finish_reason": "length"
        }
      ],
      "usage": {
        "prompt_tokens": 5,
        "completion_tokens": 7,
        "total_tokens": 12
      }
    }
  ```
- In the case of `json.data`, it seems that the endpoint of `https://api.openai.com/v1/models` might be required to be used. [Ref](https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/models) And, there is no property of `json.data[0].text`.

I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. If you want to retrieve the values of `text` from the endpoint of `https://api.openai.com/v1/completions`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (json.data && json.data.length > 0) {
  const article = json.data[0].text;
  return article;
} else {
  return 'No article found for the given topic.';
}
```

#### To:

```
if (json.choices && json.choices.length > 0) {
  const article = json.choices[0].text;
  return article;
} else {
  return 'No article found for the given topic.';
}
```

#### Note:

- If the value of `response.getContentText()` is not your expected values, this modification might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Completions of OpenAI API](https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions)

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that `console.log(response.getContentText())` outputs this:

`{ "title": "OpenAI API Example Article", "author": "John Doe", "content": "This is an example of an article retrieved using the OpenAI API. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco est laborum.", "source": "www.example.com" }`

To get the `title` and `content`, use this:

```js
  const json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  const { title, content } = json;
  console.log(title);
  console.log(content);
```

If `console.log(response.getContentText())` outputs an *array* representation like `[{ "title": ... }, { "title": ... }]`, use this to get the first array element:

```js
  const { title, content } = json[0];
```

Note that your naming is a bit misleading. The `json` variable does not point to a JSON serialization but to an object obtained from JSON with `JSON.parse()`. It would be better to call it `articleObject` or something like that.

Comment: Hi @doubleunary thanks for reply and try to help, i edit code as you mention above, but i got nothing , its just show blank cell or if i use "} else {
    return 'No article found for the given topic.';
  }" its show 'No article found for the given topic.'

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74667621/edit) the question to show what the JSON looks like. Use `console.log()` as shown in the answer, or put the JSON in a spreadsheet cell to see it there.

Comment: json output look like this {
  "title": "OpenAI API Example Article",
  "author": "John Doe",
  "content": "This is an example of an article retrieved using the OpenAI API. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco est laborum.",
  "source": "www.example.com"
}

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74667621/edit) the question to show that.

Comment: Edited the answer per the JSON structure you show.