# Why Open AI API returns a random text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch, openai-api

I'm using Apps script to create a video title out of input text. But I get irrelevant gibberish-type text in return, a mixture of some code, symbols, and random text. I have also tried different prompts but it didn't solve the issue. However, it returns good results on the website (ChatGPT).

```
var UrlFetchApp = UrlFetchApp || Import.google.script.url;
var apiUrl = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci-codex/completions";
var apiKey = "*****************";

function generateContentForMultipleRows(myRange) {
  var bulletPoints = myRange.getValues();

  bulletPoints.forEach(function (row, i) {
    var prompt1 = "create a title of up to 6 words that sums up this content" + row[0];

    var options1 = {
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey
      },
      "payload": JSON.stringify({
        "prompt": prompt1,
        "max_tokens": 100
      })
    };
    var response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, options1);
    var json1 = JSON.parse(response1.getContentText());
    var generatedContent1 = json1.choices[0].text;

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2 + i, 4).setValue(generatedContent1);
  });
}
```

- Here is the input: *"income threshold for social media must be increased
  government need to do more"*
- And here is what I get in output:

  " to provide universal access to the internet access for all people in the developing countries

  Use a for loop on the words to make similar sentences
  s = ["", government need to do more to provide universal access to the internet access for all people in the developing countries"",
  ""income threshold for social media must be increased, "",]

  for l in range(10):
  for k in range(3):
  new_s"

Comment: What is the question? P.S. The output formatting looks to require some work. on [meta] is a question title "sandbox" where you can play with the formatting options. You might also ask a question on [meta] to get tips about how to format a quetion.

Comment: What is the source that you used to get the API end-point? Have you read the API documentation to learn the HTTP request parameters?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/74667621/1595451

Comment: @Rubén My question was: why it shows random text instead of a simple title as mentioned in prompt?

Comment: @Rubén Is [chatgpt] tag being burninated or something?

Comment: @TheMaster related meta discussion https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422589/1595451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by changing API URL:

When I added 'model' in payload it raised an error that you can't specify engine and model both.
So, I deleted engine from URL and kept 'model' in payload only. That's it, it's working ok now.

Comment: Some actual code will  greatly improve this answer.

Comment: srsly. "How do I do this?" "I figured it out, kthxbye." ???

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue just yesterday, and it turns out that the URL you posted points to a deprecated endpoint.
I fixed it by removing the specific engine path from the URL and specifying the model in the request payload.
For your code,

```
var apiUrl = "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions";

"payload": JSON.stringify({
  "prompt": prompt1,
  "max_tokens": 100,
  "model": "text-davinci-003"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Try to change the model you are using:

```
var apiUrl = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/text-davinci-003/completions";
```

It seems that the davinci and davinci-codex are the dumb ones.